# Freebase MQL to list out all commons types for a given word?

Tags: json, freebase, mql

I'm trying to figure out how to write a MQL query to get a list of all the types associated to a given word.

For example I tried:

```
{
  "id":null,
  "name":null,
  "name~=": "SOME_WORD",
  "type":"/type/type",
  "domain": {
    "id": null,
    "/freebase/domain_profile/category": {
      "id": "/category/commons"
    }
  }
}​
```

I found this to list out all the Commons types or categories but haven't yet figured out how to narrow it down for a given input.

```
[{
  "id":   null,
  "name": null,
  "type": "/freebase/domain_profile",
  "category": {
    "id": "/category/commons"
  }
}]​
```

Comment: The query you give lists all *domains* (ie groups of types) which are in the category /category/commons.  Are you looking for domains, types, or instance of types?  Do you want to input "ship" and get back "sailing ship" and "military ship" or do you want your input to be "USS Constitution" and get back "sailing ship" and "military ship" or ...?

Comment: What I'm looking for is a variation of freebase suggest.  I give it a word, and it returns a list of types.  Ie.  USS Constitution would return "Ship", "Book Title", etc.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of different ways to do this with different tradeoffs for each.

1. Use the Search API with a query like this

   https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?indent=true&filter=%28all%20name{full}:%22uss%20constitution%22%29

You'll get back JSON results which look like this:

```
{
  "status": "200 OK",
  "result": [
    {
      "mid": "/m/07y14",
      "name": "USS Constitution",
      "notable": {
        "name": "Ship",
        "id": "/boats/ship"
      },
      "lang": "en",
      "score": 1401.410400
    },
    ...
```

You can make the matching more liberal by switching the "{full}" to "{phrase}" which will give you a substring match instead of an exact match.

Caveats:
 - You'll only get a single "notable type" and it's fixed by Freebase's (unknown) algorithm
 - I don't think there's a way to get both USS Constitution & U.S.S. Constitution results
 - You can get a list of all types by adding &mql_output={"type":[]}, but then you lose the "notable" type.  I don't think there's a way to get both in a single call.

1. Use MQL

This query returns the basic information that you want:

```
[{
  "name~=":"uss constitution",
  "type":[],
  "/common/topic/notable_types" : []
}]​
```

Caveats:

- It won't find "uss constitution" which is an alias rather than the primary name (there's a recipe in the [MQL cookbook](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/MQL_Cookbook#Search_for_a_value_in_two_different_properies_.28e.g._name_.26_alias.29) for that though)
- It won't find "u.s.s. constitution"
- The "notable_types" API is an MQL extension and MQL extensions aren't supported in the new Freebase API, only the legacy deprecated API
- You're tied to whatever (unknown) algorithm Freebase used to compute "notability"

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you might need something more sophisticated than this (as well as a deeper understanding of what's in Freebase), but this should get you going with the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
[{
"name": "David Bowie",
"type": []
}]
```